# How did an Egyptian visa get placed in an emergency passport not valid for travel to Egypt?

Tags: visas, passports, legal, paperwork, egypt

Because of lost passport the embassy in UAE gave me a certificate valid for one month for returning to Kyrgyzstan only but I got visa on it to enter Egypt and I travel from UAE to Egypt. After 5 years I was told that all this action was against the law ?

I want to know from the law that this was wrong and why the embassy give visa and how the UAE airport gave me exit and the Egypt Airport give me enter if it is wrong. I ask some embassies and they say it is impossible [image]

My Question is IF THE EGYPTIAN IMMIGRATION SAY THIS ACTION IS WRONG AND MOST EMBASSIES SAY THIS ACTION IS WRONG SO I NEED TO FIND IT IN THE LAW SO I CAN TAKE LEGAL ACTION , I need OFFICIAL ANSWER so i can start my LEGAL Action ?

Comment: Did you call the attention of any of the Egyptian authorities to the fact that the document was marked as for returning to Kyrgyz only?

Comment: If it's only to return to Kyrgyz republic, why there are visa pages? I assume the visa pages are for any visa required for transit stops on the way to Kyrgyzstan. So, issuing the visa might be OK in case your route to Kyrgyzstan is going through Egypt. The visa issued is annotated with (in Arabic) "A wife of an Egyptian accompanying her Egyptian kids"...

Comment: What is your travel question?

Comment: i ask some embassies they say that it is wrong , against the international Law .

Comment: i ask some embassies they say that it is wrong , against the international Law . not only the Egyptian embassy but Abu Dhabi Airport and Cairo Airport . but i am looking for  the legal text in the international Law but can not find it . can you help me

Comment: Egypt immigration say that this have never happen before and will not happen after . but they do not give me the Law sentence which f orbit this action . this is what i am looking for .

Comment: I give attention to the Egyptian embassy that this document is only for returning to Kyrgyz Republic and that the Kyrgyz Consulate say it is not possible to get any visa on it but they say they will give visa on it and they did as you can see and they also make UAE immigration give Exit Visa to Cairo - Egypt against all rules and law of The ICAO

Comment: My Question is :I need to have an official answer so i can open a legal complaint .  All this information i got is verbal , every one see this document and say it is wrong only with no official answer from the LAW

Comment: The Transit visa is different then Entry Visa and this Certificate has only Two pages for it and valid only for 30 days from date of issue

Comment: Legal action? Why? **Who** do you want to sue, for what, and what do you hope to accomplish by doing so? Have you suffered any harm? In all your all-caps shouting there is no indication that you have.

Comment: You can only sue if you can provide damages. So what are the damages done to you, against which you would like to sue, in order to get some relief? Secondly - there is no "international law"; there are just treaties. You have in possession an emergency travel document. This allows you to return to the country of issuance. Any endorsements (stamps, etc.) on this document are there to prove your exit and entry into the country. Therefore, if you were going to transit through Egypt and doing so required a visa, it is perfectly fine for it to be stamped on this temporary travel document.

Comment: The first illegality, and the root cause of all subsequent issues, was the attempt to use a document intended only for immediate return home for a trip to Egypt.

Comment: it is an International LAW as I was told by the British Embassy in Cairo and several other Embassies as well  ok .and I already open a legal case against  the Egypt MFA specially after i got a document from Abu Dhabi Immigration which proves that the Exit Visa to Cairo was given upon a falls letter from the Egyptian embassy claiming that the visa was given upon a request from the Kyrgyz consulate in Dubai which The Kyrgyz MFA and the Kyrgyz Consulate in Dubai  officially say did not happen

Comment: I contact several Embassies abroad for several countries they all say it is not possible to get a visa on an ( out pass ) and the Egyptian Embassy in Abu Dhabi say that they burn all documents after a period of time upon the LAW so they do not have any even number and date of document received from the Kyrgyz Counsulate ? and this is also official answer i got